# Does using an SSD instead of an USB drive as storage increase emulation speed in POPS?

Tags: emulation, ps2, hard-drive, ps1

I've tried playing Crash Bandicoot 2 on the "Sony PS1 Emulator for PS2" (aka POPS, `LBB-00001`) using an USB drive as storage medium for the game on a `SCPH-50004` fat PS2. It was playable but execution was somewhat slower than standard.

Using a fat PS3 HDD attached with an unofficial network port → SATA adapter as storage medium hasn't increased the performance.

Maybe with an SSD?

Comment: Your post as an answer should've been edited into the question, as it's an addition to it and not an answer, and because it looks like it has an answer some people who could help won't even read it. A mod may fix it, but IDK. Also, that unofficial adapter is probably limiting data throughput, so you can try an SSD but if it's still slow that's likely the issue - honestly no idea though as IDK anything about POPS beyond what you've said. Lol.

Comment: I added as an answer because I considered it a possible solution for a very long time, which is, from when I discovered it was possible from when I tried and posted this Q&A.

Comment: That makes sense, it's just how the site is supposed to be used - theories as comments, definitive answers as answers. Of course there's plenty of Q's and A's on most Stack Exchange sites that go against the rules, but it's up to moderators and admins to decide how to handle those things.

Comment: Using faster storage would probably not help much. It could improve loading times. But unless the performance degradation is only while the game is loading something, that would not change anything. And it is unlikely that the game is constantly loading something in the background.

Comment: Fact is, emulation can be a much more difficult problem than it seems at first glance. Sometimes you have old features in the older system which don't exist in that form in the newer system, and need to be emulated with very performance-expensive workarounds. And when a game uses those features a lot, it might run very badly in an emulator. But perhaps toying with the emulation settings could help. It might be possible to sacrifice emulation accuracy for speed. That can sometimes result in game-breaking bugs, but just as well be unnoticeable.